# ItemAdded Event in Visual Studio: Get item AND project

Tags: events, visual-studio-2012, envdte, projectitem

I develop a tool, which recognize changes made in a Visual Studio solution.
Therefore, I use dte Events like

```
solutionEvents.ProjectRemoved += cV.OnProjectRemoved;
solutionEvents.ProjectRenamed += cV.OnProjectRenamed;
projectItemsEvents.ItemAdded += cV.OnItemAdded;
```

But no I have the problem, that the **onItemAdded** Event only returns the added Item (or the full path by getting the properties), but not the project where it has been added.

First I thought about using the full path to identify the project, but this doesn't work if you add an existing item from another folder to the project.

Is there any possibility or maybe another event available to get the added Item **and** the project where it has been added?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found the answer. The *projectItemsEvents.ItemAdded* method gets the ProjectItem which has been added as input. That item has another property:

```
ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Name
```

That is how I get the name of the project, where I added the item.